# Parsec: key value pairs where value type depends on key

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse sgf files (files that describe games of go). In these files there are key value pairs of the form (in the sgf specifiction they are called property id's and property values, but i am using key and value in the hope that people will know what I am talking about when reading the title):

```
key[value]
```

or

```
key[value1][value2]...[valuen]
```

That is, there might be 1 or many values. The catch is that the type of the value depends in the key. So for example, if the key is `B` (for play a black stone in go). The value is supposed to be a coordinate described by two letters for example: `B[ab]`. It might also be that the key is `AB` (for adding a number of black stones, for setting up the board), then the value is a list of coordinates like this: `AB[ab][cd][fg]`. It could also be that the key is `C` (for a comment). Then the value is just a string `C[this is a comment]`.

Of course this could be described by the type

```
type Property = (String, [String])
```

But i think it would be nicer to have something like

```
data Property = B Coordinate | AB [Coordinate] | C String ...
```

Or maybe some other type that better utilizes the type system and won't require that I convert to and from strings all the time.

The problem is that then I would need a parser that depending on the key type returns a different value type, but I think that would cause type problems since a parser can only return one type of value.

How would you parse something like this?

Comment: Monadically. Parse the key (type of this parser: `m Key`). Then, feed this key to a function which does case analysis on the key, and chooses the appropriate parser based on the key (type: `Key -> m Property`); you can use `(>>=)` for this, or just do-notation: `do { key <- parseKey; case key of { KeyB -> parseB; KeyAB -> parseAB; keyC -> parseC }}`

Comment: Seconding @Rhymoid. This also happens to be basically the difference between an applicative functor and a monad. With a monad, you can use information you just parsed to decide how you are going to parse what's coming next. Luckily, Parsec is an instance of both Applicative and Monad. A very illustrative example of the difference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a straightforward choice, and doesn't need monadic parsing. I'll use the applicative interface to demonstrate this point.

Build a parser for each property id *and* its property values somewhat like this:

```
black = B <$> (char 'C' *> coordinate)
white = W <$> (char 'W' *> coordinate)
addBlack = AB <$> (string "AB" *> many1 coordinate)
```

(assuming you've built a `coordinate` parser that eats the brackets and returns something of type `Coordinate`).

Each one of those has type `Parser Property` (with your second, better structured data type), so now we just get the parser to choose between them. If the property ids all have different first letters, when you use the parser for the wrong id, it will fail without consuming input, which is ideal for the choice operator:

```
myparser = black <|> white <|> addBlack
```

But I suspect there's an `AW` id for adding white stones, so we'd need to warn that they overlap using try, which backtracks when a parser fails:

```
mybetterparser = black <|> white <|> (try addBlack <|> try addWhite)
```

I've bracketed together parsers with a common start and used try on them to go back to the beginning.